simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format at vendor/simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode/src/Image.php:21)
This error occurs when i'm try generate qr-code by simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode in docker enviroment. It works without errors on the local machine (without docker)
Params:
php8.3
php-ext:

bcmath
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
gd
hash
iconv
imagick
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
random
readline
redis
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
sockets
sodium
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

Laravel 10.42
simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode 4.2
Code:
        $path = storage_path(sprintf('app/accounts/qr/%s.png', 'SOME_LOGIN'));

        QrCode::format('png')
            ->size(500)
            ->style('dot', 0.9)
            ->eye('square')
            ->merge('/resources/images/qr_custom_mask.png', 1)
            ->errorCorrection('H')
            ->margin(3)
            ->generate(
                json_encode(['login' => 'SOME_LOGIN', 'pass' => 'SOME_PASS']),
                $path
            );

All directories and resources in the paths exist
This code works in FPM mode, but in CLI (queue, tinker, schewdule) throws this error.
[2024-06-24 18:03:27] production.ERROR: imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format at /var/www/vendor/simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode/src/Image.php:21)

I tried to rebuild container, manipulates flags with json_encode, clear cache and restart queues. It doesn't work anyway. Please help!!!

My apologize! I found out what the problem is. Git LFS plugin uploaded a broken image during the deployment process
